# Using the '\n' and '\t' escape sequences in Decimal Format?

Tags: java

My task for my online programming class is to write a short program that calculates your bill at a restaurant. This restaurant bill is supposed to display the cost of the meal before taxes (make up your own amount), Harmonized Sales Tax (13%) and the cost of the meal including taxes. I decided to add the tip in just to add more detail.

The output of the program should be formatted to 2 decimal places. I am supposed to use the /n and /t escape sequences? What code am I to use for this and where would I put it?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    double mealCharge; 
    double tax; 
    double tip; 
    double total; 

            try ( 
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            System.out.print("Enter the charge for the meal: ");
            mealCharge = keyboard.nextDouble();

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("\"%.2f");


            // Calculate the tax.
            tax = calculateTax (mealCharge);


            // Calculate the tip.
            tip = calculateTip (mealCharge);

            // Calculate the total.
            total = calculateTotal (mealCharge, tax, tip);

            // Display the results.
            System.out.println("Meal Charge:................... $" + mealCharge);
            System.out.println("Tax:............................$" + tax);
            System.out.println("Tip:............................$" + tip);
            System.out.println("Total:..........................$" + total);


        }
}



static double calculateTax (double mealCharge) {
    return mealCharge * TAX_RATE;
}


static double calculateTip (double mealCharge) {
    return mealCharge * TIP_PERCENT;
}


static double calculateTotal (double mealCharge, double tax, double tip) {
    return mealCharge + tax + tip;
}
```

}

Comment: mmm, how the output should look like?

Comment: I'm asking what I would use for the decimal format for the output of the bill. and where would I put it in my code? between each calculation, or? For example this is what shows up: Meal Charge: $20.0, Tax:.$2.6, Tip:$3.0, Total:$25.6

Comment: Maybe you should try it, and if it's not to your liking, update the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(String.format("Meal Charge:................... $%.2f" , mealCharge));
```

Comment: Sure thing!  Check out https://www.dotnetperls.com/format-java for more help in this area.